# Is that possible to load a Json or CSV file in memory and run MongoDB query on it?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am developing a software by C# and MongoDB. I was wondering if it is possible to load a JSON or CSV file in memory and run MongoDB queries on it. One solution is import data to a collection and run the queries but I want to load the data in memory instead of database and then run queries. Is that possible?

Comment: No it's not currently possible as of MongoDB 3.6.4. What is your use case and what are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have a lot of users. I want to keep some aggregation results for each user in a specific file. Then based on user, run some queries just on specific file which has a few documents instead of huge collection and show to related user.

Comment: So are you faced with performance issues when executing those queries, or are you looking for a more efficient way to do it? Do you mind updating the question with those additional details and some example documents and queries you're planning to do?

Comment: Yes. Actually the main problem is performance. We have simple collections with about 8 fields like `Value`, `_id`, `Name`, `Date` , ...  without nested fields. The count of documents in best way after using `$match` in aggregation pipeline is about 5 millions.Now just a simple `$group` takes at least 2 seconds. and it is a lot for us. I was looking for a way to load that documents in memory and run some queries on it.

Comment: Please update the question with the relevant details, example documents, and the query you're trying to do.